# C# thread safe text update on dynamically created text boxes

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I know how to do a thread safe update on a text box that was already defined http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx .... how can i do this on text boxes that were generated later on in the program? You advice  is much appreciated.

Comment: You'd do this exactly the same way.  Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: The text box in question is different for each thread. How will i tell it which box is next without passing its name into a parameter?

Comment: What does it mean when you say "which box is next?" You're implying some kind of order which you have not told us anything about. To be more precise: **it's best to pretend like we have no clue what you're talking about and explain exactly what you're doing.**

Comment: I have x number of threads. I have the same number of text boxes which are dynamically created. I need to update the text before a timer runs out.

Comment: I want all the threads to stop when the timer runs out

Comment: @user1261710 Whoa, one question at a time.  What you asked has absolutely nothing to do with timers.

Comment: Sorry if i came across as demanding.... i just have this project to do with very little info....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given some `TextBox` object, just invoke on it:

```
TextBox foo = new TextBox(...);

// Code to add the new box to the form has been omitted; presumably
// you do this already.

Action update = delegate { foo.Text = "Changed!"; };

if (foo.InvokeRequired) {
    foo.Invoke(update);
} else {
    update();
}
```

If you're using this pattern a lot, this extension method might be helpful:

```
public static void AutoInvoke(
    this System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke self,
    Action action)
{
    if (self == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("self");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    if (self.InvokeRequired) {
        self.Invoke(action);
    } else {
        action();
    }
}
```

Then you can reduce your code to:

```
foo.AutoInvoke(() => foo.Text = "Changed!");
```

This will just do the right thing, executing the delegate on the main GUI thread whether or not you are currently executing on it.

Comment: Hey that's cool. I can also loop through several of them that way.

Comment: You can also use anonymous delegates.  In this case, they compile to exactly the same thing.  (Lambdas can be used to instantiate expression tree objects, while anonymous delegates cannot.  Both can be used to instantiate delegate objects, and are exactly equivalent in this regard.)

Answer (score 0):

We definitely need more information here, but from what I can gather, you're lamenting the fact that the thread's main function doesn't take any arguments.  You could make the textbox(es) members of the surrounding class, and access them that way.  If you go this route though, be sure to use a mutex or some other locking device for threads.

Comment: Basically the user will enter x number of threads... text boxes are dynamically created on the form for each thread

Comment: Each thread has a counter loop it will quit when the timer goes off. The user will pick the time as well. The threads are running at the same time and will quit at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your input about this problem.

Comment: Right now i have a shared boolean to check if the timer went off..  not sure if a mutex is required for this case or not.